# ReactJS: Accessing child components properties in parent

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to wrap semantic ui elements with React so that they are re-usable within my app.

```javascript
var s_input = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return this.transferPropsTo(
                <div className = "ui input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.placeHolderTxt} ref="text"/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    });
```

I am using the the input component inside a from:

```html
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
    <s_input placeHolder={this.props.placeHolderTxt||''}></s_input>
</form>
```

And here's my handleSubmit method:

```javascript
handleSubmit:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = this.refs.text.getDOMNode().value.trim();
               this.refs.text.getDOMNode().value = '';
               this.props.onSubmit(text);
}
```

The problem I have is trying to access the **text** property of the **input** component when submitting the form so that I can do something like `this.refs.text.getDOMNode().value.trim();`. Does anybody have any idea on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Could you show the full `handleSubmit()` method?

Comment: I have edited the question and included my code for handleSubmit()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
var input = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return this.transferPropsTo(
            <div className = "ui input">
                <input className="ui input" type="text" placeHolder={this.props.placeHolderTxt} ref="text"/>
            </div>
        )
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.refs.text.getDOMNode().value;
    }
});
```

Then you can do `<s_input ref="myinput" />` and `this.refs.myinput.getValue()`. You could also structure your code to pass an onChange callback and then read `e.target.value` the same way you'd deal with any other controlled component: [Forms](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).